# Get User Details from User Profile using Web Service in SPD 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, web-services, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I want to retrieve the user properties like Group,Email,Manager from User Profile using Web service in SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow. I trying with `Call HTTP Web Service` Action. Please explain me how to achieve this in detail?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create `EndPoint` workflow variable with value
   `[%Workflow_Context:Current Site
   URL%]]/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$filter=(ID eq
   [%Workflow_Context:AssignedTo%])`
2. Add `Build dictionary` action to get the the response in a JSON format you will have to update the Accept and Content-Type http headers of your Rest http call; more specifically:

> ```
> Accept : application/json;odata=verbose 
> Content-Type :application/json;odata=verbose:
> ```

3. Go to property of call HTTP web service action >> set dictionary
   output to `RequestHeaders` parameter as shown in image.

   [image]
4. Get result from variavle as shown in image
   [image]

   Reference Link: https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Please elaborate the 2nd point?

Comment: Add build dictionary action. Click on this and add both headers. I have given reference link. It will explain more specifically.

Comment: Great. Finally you got it and also clear about it.

Comment: Yeah Thank You again. Vote my question if it is useful for others.